# How do I create widget manually (dynamic) in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to create a dynamic `RecyclerView`. Already many good examples here, but can not reach the conclusion of my doubt.
My problem is not able to understand how to create my `wedgets` manually without relate to `xml`. I need to create as well.

I need to create  `RadioButtons`, `CheckBox`, `EditText`, `TextView` and necessary, unrelated to the `xml`.

Follow my class below:

```
public class AdapterPergunta extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPergunta.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayAdapter<PerguntaPOJO> adpPergunta;
//private ArrayAdapter<RespostaPOJO> adpResposta;
private List<RespostaPOJO> listResposta;
private RespostaDAO respostaDAO;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private int mTipoPergunta;
private RecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta;
private Context mcontext;
private RadioGroup myRadiogroup;
private RadioButton myRadiobutton;
private PerguntaPOJO perguntaPOJO;
private int contPergunta;
private boolean alimentou;

private static final int CREATE_RADIOBUTTON = 0;
private static final int CREATE_CHECKBOX = 1;
private static final int CREATE_EDITTEXT = 2;
private static final int CREATE_TEXTVIEW = 0;


public AdapterPergunta(Context context, ArrayAdapter<PerguntaPOJO> adp){
    adpPergunta = adp;
    mcontext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    respostaDAO = new RespostaDAO(mcontext);
    perguntaPOJO = new PerguntaPOJO();
    contPergunta=0;
    alimentou = false;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Chamado quando tem necessidade de criar uma nova View
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_adapter_pergunta_recyclerview, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    listResposta = respostaDAO.listaRespostaAdapter(mcontext, adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta());
    alimentou = true;
    contPergunta = contPergunta + 1;

    try {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case CREATE_TEXTVIEW:
                GrupoPergunta textView = (GrupoPergunta) holder;
                textView.mTextView.setText(adpPergunta.getItem(position).getDescricao());
                textView.mTextView.setId(adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta());
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Erro ao criar GrupoPergunta", e.toString());
    }
    Log.d("Position: ", String.valueOf(position));
    Log.d("Pergunta: ",String.valueOf(adpPergunta.getItem(position).getIdpergunta()+"-"+
            adpPergunta.getItem(position).getDescricao()));

    //adpResposta.clear();
    try {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceInUp)
                .duration(700)
                .playOn(holder.itemView);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //tamanho da lista
    int count = adpPergunta.getCount();
    return count;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int posicao = 0;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return CREATE_TEXTVIEW;
    }
    return posicao;
}

public class GrupoPergunta extends MyViewHolder{
    TextView mTextView;
    RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
    RadioButton mRadioBuitton;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
    EditText mEditText;
    public GrupoPergunta(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemPerguntaViewHolver);

    }
}


public void setRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta(RecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta r) {
    mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta = r;
}

public void addAdpterItem(PerguntaPOJO perguntaPOJO, int position) {
    adpPergunta.add(perguntaPOJO);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView tv_pergunta_adapter;
    public RadioGroup rgItemAdapter;
    public RadioButton rbItemAdapter;
    public LinearLayout lnItemAdapterPergunta;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_pergunta_adapter = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pegunta_adapter);
        lnItemAdapterPergunta = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lnItemAdapterPergunta);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta != null) {
            mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerAdapterPergunta.onClickListener(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

}

I hope I have explained well my question to understand.

Comment: paste the full class please

Comment: I'll edit my question, putting the entire class.

Comment: Okay ... question edited for better understanding.

Comment: oh i see what you are doing. you are attempting to make a question-answer layout, with answers varying from radioButtons, Edittext, etc. You should create a xml layout for each type of question. and inflate the different layout of your chosing

Comment: That's it. But what I find with the problem is that I can not set a specific layout, because the amount of change answers question to question. You have a set amount of responses for each question. That both questions that the answers will be the RadioButton type, as for those that will be the type CheckBox.

Comment: in that scenario, create a custom widget and create methods to add those items dynamically in the widget. And then in the adapter call those methods to create how many answers you need

Comment: How to do this? I get to create radio button, but when carried in my activity, the data were wrong. Appeared answers to wrong questions and when I rolled, returned to appear the ones I had scored before the new questions. Understood? How can I do this?

Comment: From what it appears, you are kind of new to android world. You would need to create a custom widget and create the answers dynamically, as i said, providing methods to do so and calling them from the adapter. This kind of stuff is like intermediate-android, and not so easy to do with few practice. I'm sorry i couldn't be more helpfull

Comment: I'm really new to android, so I come here for help. But thank you for your attention and for the tip.